# I need to implement SimpleSMALPHP in java app

Tags: java, php

I have recived an app builded in a Wildfly 17 server, java and angularJs.

My problem is i need to implement a SSO with SimpleSMALphp and i cant find the way to do it without rebuild all the app.

Ive found an Apache module that can parse auth cookies from php to other languages, but nothing like that i can use in wildfly.

If anyone knows of a guide or something similar, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Why use a SAML library in a language you don't use? Find a SAML library for Java.

Comment: Why not keep it in it's native language it was built on, and just program in Java?  --  Else you'll most likely need to build an API to talk between the two languages to send auth tokens etc etc .. Just sounds -- messy ..

Comment: The previous developer did not respect the requirements of the project and now I have inherited this mess. It is the client's requirement to use their own sso, and this is from SimpleSAMLphp

Comment: SAML is a standard. SimpleSAML.php is merely an implementation of SAML in PHP. If the client's own SSO is SAML based, you should be able to use it with any SAML library.

Comment: Ah, ok. This was much easier than how I was determined to do it. Solved all my doubts then. Thnk u.